# ArrayList not being displayed in RecyclerView

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm trying to display an ArrayList of Integers inside of a RecyclerView, the Integer values in the ArrayList are downloaded from JSON, all that is done, the thing I need help with is to display them in a RecyclerView.

This is my code so far but the RecyclerView does not display anything.

**All code updated to my current code**

Here's part of the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ActivityMainViewModel viewmodel;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
MainAdapter mAdapter;
public static ArrayList<Integer> rideList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

    viewmodel = new ActivityMainViewModel();
    binding.setViewmodel(viewmodel);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mAdapter = new MainAdapter(rideList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Here's the MainAdapter class:

```
class MainAdapter extends android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Integer> rideList;

public MainAdapter(ArrayList<Integer> rideList)
{
    this.rideList = rideList;
}

@Override
public MainAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MainAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    holder.rideHeight.setText(String.valueOf(rideList.get(position)));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return rideList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView rideHeight;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        rideHeight = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rideHeight_textView);
    }
}
```

}

row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rideHeight_textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I know that it probably looks a mess but that's because I have been searching both on google and youtube on how to use RecyclerView so I might have mixed from different tutorials and tried somethings myself.

Thanks!

Edit: JsonData code added on request:

JsonData:

```
public class JsonData
{
public ObservableField<String> dropHeight = new ObservableField<>();
public ObservableField<String> rideCount = new ObservableField<>();
int eID;
int sID;

public JsonData()
{
    dropHeight.set("");
    rideCount.set("");
}

public void downloadFromSkistar()
{
    if (SettingsActivity.submitClicked)
    {
        eID = SettingsActivity.x;
        sID = SettingsActivity.y;
    }
    else
    {
        eID = 3206;
        sID = 11;
    }

    try
    {
        URL url = new URL("https://www.skistar.com/myskistar/api/v2/views/statisticspage.json?entityId=" + eID + "&seasonId=" + sID + " ");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        // Starts the query
        conn.connect();

        int response = conn.getResponseCode();
        Log.i("AndroidExample", "Response: " + response);

        if (response == 200)
        {
            String json = getJson(conn.getInputStream());

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("rideStatistics");

            int reponame = 0;
            int rHeight = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject skiRun = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                reponame += skiRun.getInt("height");

                rHeight += skiRun.getInt("height");
                MainActivity.rideList.add(new Integer(rHeight));
                rHeight = 0;
            }
            final int height = reponame;
            final int count =  jsonArray.length();

            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    dropHeight.set("" + height);
                    rideCount.set("" + count);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.i("AndroidExample", "Error");
    }
    finally
    {
    }
}

private String getJson(InputStream stream) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader reader;
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        builder.append(line + '\n');
    }
    //Should be placed in finally
    stream.close();
    return builder.toString();
}
}
```

Comment: Check if `JsonData.rideList` contains data or not ...

Comment: Code looks fine .. First check your JSON data is there or not. Debug your code. put break-point where you are trying to parse data... Check Result

Comment: JsonData.rideList seems to be empty at that point, how do i get the JsonData class to run first?

Comment: Because the ArrayList does get populated in JsonData, i just need it to run first.

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez how do i get JsonData to run first so that the list gets populated?

Comment: share your class where you are populating `JsonData`

Comment: try my solution. see if that works

Comment: @nihal_softy I now updated the question with my current code, this current code I have worked when I created a hardcoded ArrayList of Integers. This means that the only problem now is that JsonData has to run from OnCreate since the ArrayList gets populated in JsonData. Would really appreciate some help, no idea what to do next.

Comment: @random1234 okay.. Please give me your JSON URL.. I will give you overall project after implementing everything.. this help I can do for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did to solve it, and btw I'm also using the SwipeRefreshLayout.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ActivityMainViewModel viewmodel;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
MainAdapter mAdapter;
public static ArrayList<Integer> rideList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

    viewmodel = new ActivityMainViewModel();
    binding.setViewmodel(viewmodel);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mAdapter = new MainAdapter(rideList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    viewmodel.jdDownloadFromSkistar();

    final SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipelayout);;
    swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.refresh,R.color.refresh1,R.color.refresh2);

    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {

            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

            refreshRecyclerView();

            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });
}

private void refreshRecyclerView()
{
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

So what I did was make a call to the jdDownloadFromSkistar(); Method and when I swipe to refresh it updates the adapter by using the notifyDataSetChanged(); method.

Answer (score 0):

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
mAdapter = new MainAdapter(JsonData.rideList, MainActivity.this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

adapter:

```
class MainAdapter extends android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        private ArrayList<Integer> rideList = new ArrayList<>();
        private Context context;

        public MainAdapter(ArrayList<Integer> rideList, Context context)
        {

    this.context = context;
      this.rideList = rideList;
    }

    @Override
    public MainAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MainAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        holder.rideHeight.setText(String.valueOf(rideList.get(position)));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return rideList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView rideHeight;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            rideHeight = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rideHeight_textView);
        }
    }
    }
```

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rideHeight_textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In the first code part the "context" and "donatesListAdapter" in MainActivity are red.

Comment: Edited, test again plz

Comment: The ArrayList is empty, the problem is that it gets populated in JsonData, so i need that to run first or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like..

1. Model..to set value and get value

   ```
   public class CustomModel {
    private  int it;

     public int getIt() {
      return it;
      }

     public void setIt(int it) {
      this.it = it;
       }
    }
   ```
2. Adapter ...

   ```
        private class  MainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.ViewHolder>{

   public MainAdapter(ArrayList<CustomModel> list){

       dataSet = list;
   }

   @Override
   public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

       View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(
               R.layout.row, null);

       itemLayoutView.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

       MainAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new MainAdapter.ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);

       return viewHolder;
   }


   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
       CustomModel cardModel = dataSet.get(position);
       viewHolder.rideHeight_textView.setText(String.valueOf(cardModel.getId()));

   }

   @Override
   public int getItemCount() {
       return dataSet.size();
   }

   public void updateList(List<CustomModel> temp) {
       dataSet = (ArrayList<CustomModel>) temp;
       notifyDataSetChanged();
   }

   public  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

       public TextView rideHeight_textView;



       public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
           super(itemLayoutView);

           rideHeight_textView = (TextView) itemLayoutView  .findViewById(R.id.rideHeight_textView);


           itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {
                  //action ****
               }
           });
       }
        }

   }
   ```
3. Just call like

   ```
    ArrayList<CustomModel> menuList = new ArrayList<>();
   CustomModel c = new CustomModel();
   c.setIt(1);
   recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
   // ListView
   recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Your activity.this));
   // create an Object for Adapter
   MainAdapter mAdapter = new MainAdapter(menuList);
   // set the adapter object to the Recyclerview
   recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
   ```
4. row.xml

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:background="#ffffff"
       android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/rideHeight_textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For starters you are not calling your data fetcher method in `JsonData` class. Your code is kind of messy so you can try the following solution:

In your adapter class add this method:

```
public void setList(ArrayList<Integer> rideList)
{
this.rideList = rideList;
notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Then in you `JsonData` class add:

```
private MainAdapter adapter;

public JsonData(MainAdapter adapter)
{
this.adapter = adapter;
dropHeight.set("");
rideCount.set("");
}
```

And change `downloadFromSkistar` to:

```
public void downloadFromSkistar()
{
if (SettingsActivity.submitClicked)
{
    eID = SettingsActivity.x;
    sID = SettingsActivity.y;
}
else
    {
        eID = 3206;
        sID = 11;
    }
 new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Integer>>() {

                            @Override
                            protected List<Integer> doInBackground(Void... voids) {

try
{

    URL url = new 
 URL("https://www.skistar.com/myskistar/api/v2/views/statisticspage.json?
 entityId=" + eID + "&seasonId=" + sID + " ");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    // Starts the query
    conn.connect();

    int response = conn.getResponseCode();
    Log.i("AndroidExample", "Response: " + response);

    if (response == 200)
    {
        String json = getJson(conn.getInputStream());

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("rideStatistics");

        int reponame = 0;
        int rHeight = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject skiRun = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            reponame += skiRun.getInt("height");

            rHeight += skiRun.getInt("height");
            rideList.add(new Integer(rHeight));
            rHeight = 0;
        }

    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.i("AndroidExample", "Error");
}
finally
{
}

                                return rideList;
                            }

                            @Override
                            protected void onPostExecute(List<Integer> list) 
{
                                super.onPostExecute(list);
                                adapter.setList(rideList);
                            }
                        };

}
```

And in the end finally change `MainActivity` to:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ActivityMainViewModel viewmodel;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
MainAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

viewmodel = new ActivityMainViewModel();
binding.setViewmodel(viewmodel);

recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
mAdapter = new MainAdapter(JsonData.rideList);

recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
new JsonData(mAdapter).downloadFromSkistar();
}
```

PS: You are going to get `NetworkOnMainThread` exception. So try to add the network code in `AsyncTask`

Comment: RecyclerView is still empty =(

Comment: are you getting response from the url ?

Comment: I now updated the question with my current code, this current code I have worked when I created a hardcoded ArrayList of Integers. This means that the only problem now is that JsonData has to run from OnCreate since the ArrayList gets populated in JsonData. Would really appreciate some help, no idea what to do next.

Comment: eidited my answer. have a try